# React Re-rendering and Redux Issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, useselector

When we use useSelector hook all the components where I have used the useSelector hooks gets re rendered whenever i change the state

how to avoid this and is there any other way I can prevent the components from re rendering

Comment: Did you try useEffect or useMemo for other data?

Comment: Could you privide a minimal working example? Could you specify what problem is the re-rendering causing?

Comment: That's kind of what the `useSelector` hook is for. When the state the selector is subscribed to updates, it will trigger a component rerender so it can access the current state value. Is there some issue you are seeing because of this behavior? Please [edit] to explain what and ask about the real issue is that you are trying to fix and not the current question trying to block React from rerendering when it needs to. Please also include a [mcve] so we can actually see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

useSelector takes a second argument which is a function that checks if the previous and current state are equal to determine when to update.

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// Pass it as the second argument directly
const selectedData = useSelector(selectorReturningObject, shallowEqual)

// or pass it as the `equalityFn` field in the options argument
const selectedData = useSelector(selectorReturningObject, {
  equalityFn: shallowEqual,
})
```